# How to split zip files using Perl

Tags: perl, zip

I have a zip file which is of size larger than 1000MB. I want to split it into multiple compressed zip files depending on size. It will be great if each split zip files are of 10 MB size.
My input will be zip file and output should be multiple compressed zip files

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 
  use strict;
 use utf8;
 use Archive::Zip qw(:ERROR_CODES :CONSTANTS);

  my $file = $ARGV[0];

 my $filesize = -s $file;
 print "Size: $filesize\n";
```

Appreciate your help
Thanks

Comment: Look into the [`zipsplit`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zipsplit) program.

Comment: If you still want to solve this with Perl you could perhaps start with google-ing 'knapsack perl' or 'multiple knapsack perl' for existing modules. Or simplifying by just moving to the next .zip-file when a certain limit is reached for the last. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Multiple_knapsack_problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Splitted Zip for this.

Refer to https://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=534408

Its purpose is to arrange the files to be sent in order to produce multiple ZIP archives, each of which remains valid and self-contained.

You can also use "split-archive" functionality of "zip" itself

```
$ zip -r -s 10m file.zip directory/ => using the "--split-size" option.
```